# How to implement tooltip mode "single" in Chart.js 3?

Tags: chart.js

It seems that in Chart.js there was a tooltip mode "single", which resulted in displaying only a single entry in the tooltip label (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.7.3/general/interactions/modes.html#single-deprecated).

Chart.js 3 displays multiple adjacent items in tooltip by default. Is there a way to adjust the behavior to display a single nearest item?

Comment: How quick are people with downvotes these days. Any explanation for the downvotes?

Comment: Did you find a solution to display a single point @Rogach ?
I am encountering the exact same issue...

Comment: @Germain - Yes, but I had to re-implement the tooltip text generation (by overriding the plugins.tooltip.callbacks.title and plugins.tooltip.callbacks.label in options). But we are moving away from Chart.js in general, we are now using Echarts and it's much more pleasant.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the docs you can use mode `nearest` with intersect true to return the nearest point or you can use mode `point`

Comment: Tried both, both still result in multiple labels being shown.

Comment: As described in the docs, mode "point" "Finds *all* of the items that intersect the point", and "all" kind of implies "multiple possible".

Comment: Mode "nearest" with intersect: true also returns several points if there are several points nearby that intersect with the mouse position.

Answer (score 0):

**intersect** with **nearest** mode do the trick for me:

```
this.chartOptions = {
    interaction: {
        intersect: true,
        mode: "nearest",
    },
};
```

[image]